# Subscripts and superscripts on accented math characters

Tags: math-mode, accents, subscripts, superscripts

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

${x_i}^j$ works as expected but not with an hat as in ${\hat{x}_i}^j$.
The way I found to make it work is $\mbox{$\hat{x}_i$}^j$.  Is there
an nicer solution?


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Do you perhaps mean `$x_i^j$` and  `${\hat{x}_i^j}$`?

Comment: No, I mean ${x_i}^j$, so that exponent $j$ appears to the right of $x_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the hat centered of the "x" and the "j" not too close, the most simple code would be  `\hat{x}_i{}^{j}`. This  way the height of the symbol is not taken into account, so is not exactly the same result, but `{{}\hat{x}_i}^{j}` obtain exactly the same result. Some comparisons:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
$\widehat{x_i}^j$ \dotfill{\tiny   \verb|$\widehat{x_i}^j$|}\par
$\hat{x}_i{}^{j}$ \dotfill{\tiny    \verb|$\hat{x}_i{}^{j}$|}\par 
${{}\hat{x}_i}^{j}$ \dotfill{\tiny    \verb|${{}\hat{x}_i}^{j}$|}\par 
${\strut\hat{x}_i}^{j}$ \dotfill{\tiny    \verb|$\strut\hat{x}_i{}^{j}$|}\par 
$\mbox{$\hat{x}_i$}^j$  \dotfill{\tiny  \verb|$\mbox{$\hat{x}_i$}^j$|}\par
$\hat{x_i}^j$ \dotfill{\tiny   \verb|$\hat{x_i}^j$|}\par     
${\hat{x}_i}^j$ \dotfill{\tiny   \verb|${\hat{x}_i}^j$|}\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: To get the exact same result as with the \mbox{}, I am now using ${\hat{x}_i{}}^j$.

Comment: @user94293 Unfortunately, not the same. I have updated the answer to not misleading, but it is already explained in the linked question.